# zustand typescript persist how to type store

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-state

I've this simple store

```
interface CartState {
  cart: { [id: string]: CartDto };
  addItem: ({ id, image, name, price }: Omit<CartDto, "quantity">) => void;
  removeItem: (id: string) => void;
  reset: () => void;
}
export const useCart = create<CartState>((set, get) => ({
  cart: {},
  addItem: ({ id, image, name, price }) => {
    set(() => {
      const cart = get().cart;
      if (!cart[id]) {
        cart[id] = {
          id,
          image,
          name,
          price,
          quantity: 0
        };
      }

      cart[id].quantity += 1;

      return { cart };
    });
  },
  removeItem: (id) => {
    set(() => {
      const cart = get().cart;

      if (!cart[id]) {
        return { cart };
      }

      const newQuantity = cart[id].quantity - 1;
      if (newQuantity <= 0) {
        delete cart[id];
      } else {
        cart[id].quantity = newQuantity;
      }

      return { cart };
    });
  },
  reset: () => {
    set(() => {
      return { cart: {} };
    });
  }
}));
```

and it works very well.
Problem is when I try to add persist

```
export const useCart = create<CartState>(
  persist(
    (set, get) => ({
      cart: {},
      addItem: ({ id, image, name, price }) => {
        set(() => {
          const cart = get().cart;
          if (!cart[id]) {
            cart[id] = {
              id,
              image,
              name,
              price,
              quantity: 0
            };
          }

          cart[id].quantity += 1;

          return { cart };
        });
      },
      removeItem: (id) => {
        set(() => {
          const cart = get().cart;

          if (!cart[id]) {
            return { cart };
          }

          const newQuantity = cart[id].quantity - 1;
          if (newQuantity <= 0) {
            delete cart[id];
          } else {
            cart[id].quantity = newQuantity;
          }

          return { cart };
        });
      },
      reset: () => {
        set(() => {
          return { cart: {} };
        });
      }
    }),
    {
      name: "cart",
      getStorage: () => localStorage
    }
  )
);
```

I've got this error:

> Argument of type '(set: SetState, get: GetState,
> api: StoreApiWithPersist<{ cart: {}; addItem: ({ id, image, name,
> price }: Omit<CartDto, "quantity">) => void; removeItem: (id: string)
> => void; reset: () => void; }>) => { ...; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'StoreApi | StateCreator<CartState,
> SetState, GetState, StoreApi>'.
> Type '(set: SetState, get: GetState, api:
> StoreApiWithPersist<{ cart: {}; addItem: ({ id, image, name, price }:
> Omit<CartDto, "quantity">) => void; removeItem: (id: string) => void;
> reset: () => void; }>) => { ...; }' is not assignable to type
> 'StateCreator<CartState, SetState, GetState,
> StoreApi>'.

I've tried with

```
export const useCart = create<StoreApiWithPersist<CartState>>
```

with no luck.

What's the right way, please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit: PhilJay's answer is the best answer. This answer is outdated even though marked as the best.

I had the same issue. What I did was:

```
import create, { GetState, SetState } from 'zustand';
import { devtools, persist, StoreApiWithPersist } from 'zustand/middleware';

const useAssetStore = create<AssetStoreType, SetState<AssetStoreType>, GetState<AssetStoreType>, StoreApiWithPersist<AssetStoreType>>(
persist(
    devtools((set) => ({
        logo: '',
    })),
    { name: 'assetStore', version: 1, getStorage: () => localStorage }
));
```

So, in your case, you need to explicitly add:

```
create<CartState, SetState<CartState>, GetState<CartState>, StoreApiWithPersist<CartState>>
```

Comment: As the official docs said, there is no specific type you could add when you add a Zustand middleware.
https://docs.pmnd.rs/zustand/guides/typescript#using-middlewares

Answer (score 48):

When using zustand with TypeScript, you should use the **curried** version of `create<T>(...)` as stated in the first paragraph of the [docs](https://docs.pmnd.rs/zustand/guides/typescript).

Replacing

```
  export const useCart = create<CartState>(
```

by

```
  export const useCart = create<CartState>()(
```

should solve the problem.

Comment: This answer should be marked as correct imho.

Comment: I dont understand but worked.

Comment: @nerkn currying is a workaround for https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10571

Answer (score 4):

Type `persist` instead of typing `create`. So in your case:

```
export const useCart = create(
  persist<CartState>(
    (set, get) => ({
      cart: {},
      addItem: ({ id, image, name, price }) => {
        set(() => {
          const cart = get().cart;
          if (!cart[id]) {
            cart[id] = {
              id,
              image,
              name,
              price,
              quantity: 0
            };
          }

          cart[id].quantity += 1;

          return { cart };
        });
      },
      removeItem: (id) => {
        set(() => {
          const cart = get().cart;

          if (!cart[id]) {
            return { cart };
          }

          const newQuantity = cart[id].quantity - 1;
          if (newQuantity <= 0) {
            delete cart[id];
          } else {
            cart[id].quantity = newQuantity;
          }

          return { cart };
        });
      },
      reset: () => {
        set(() => {
          return { cart: {} };
        });
      }
    }),
    {
      name: "cart",
      getStorage: () => localStorage // Note that this is not necessary, since localstorage is used by default
    }
  )
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example from the documentation that demonstrates the implementation in TypeScript:

```
interface BearState {
  bears: number
  increase: (by: number) => void
}

const useBearStore = create<BearState>()(
  devtools(
    persist(
      (set) => ({
        bears: 0,
        increase: (by) => set((state) => ({ bears: state.bears + by })),
      }),
      {
        name: 'bear-storage',
      }
    )
  )
)
```

Here you got link: https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand#typescript-usage